# Push controller after Present modal on didReceiveRemoteNotification method in appDelegate

Tags: ios, swift

I need to push a viewController inside a present completation handler that is inside didReceiveRemoteNotification appDelegate's method.

My views/controller struct:

Splash > LoginController (UIViewController) > HomeController (UINavigationController)

When I receive a new notification I want to push a new UIViewController from my HomeController.

**What I have until now:**

Receive notification and get data
Get window.rootViewController (LoginController) in didReceiveRemoteNotification 
Present navBarController with present(_:animated:completion:) method (Doing this I can see HomeController since the controller is the rootviewcontroller)

**What I need?**

Push ProductDetailController

**I already try:**

push from navBarController
push from new instance from HomeController

**What I got (but don't want to)**

present ProductDetailController as modal on completation handler.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a `Bool` value in defaults in  `didReceiveRemoteNotification` say to `true` and check it in `viewDidAppear` of `HomeController`

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated:bool) {

   super.viewDidAppear(animetd:animated)

   if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey:"presentDetails") {

      let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "detailsID") as! ProductDetailController

      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

      UserDefaults.standard.set(false,forKey:"presentDetails")

   }

 }
```

Comment: But if I do that, all the time that the user entering on the app he push detail controller. I just want to push detail when the user received a notification
edit:
Wow I got it! use defaults to indicate if is or not a notification, right?

Comment: Got it... Agree with you, but honestly I didn't want to add one more 
 responsibility to HomeController, but I think that's the only way to do that.

Thanks man!

Comment: @GustavoBergamo Actually you can embed the login in the navigation and when you receive the notification get the root as the navigation and push directly

Comment: At the first version of the app, LoginController was embed in the Navigation, I took it off because UX team told me that it would be better. Thanks